# Actionscript 3: Adding a MovieClip (from library but not on stage) to a Sprite declared within a seperate class

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, movieclip

What I am trying to do is add a MovieClip which I have created, but deleted from the actual stage itself, from a seperate class to a sprite which I declare in the document class.
The link between the main document class and the others works fine, as well as references to the stage, from the class in question.

It is only one line of the function which is giving me the error: Type was not found, or is not compile-time constant:SequenceA

I have already tried changing the settings for 'Export for Actionscript' in the library properties and still get the same message every time.

Pretty lost with this one so any help is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: where else does `appRef` and `sequenceA` exist? if you are creating it within this function, sequenceA has not yet been declared anywhere...and this also implies that sequenceA is a child of appRef yes?

Comment: Sorry, appRef is declared above it, it is a reference to the stage. I have used it already and it works fine. sequenceA is the MovieClip in the library that I am trying to access

Comment: what happens if you dont use appRef? give sequenceA a class name of SequenceA and try `var seqA:sequenceA = new SequenceA;` and see if it complains. This will at least confirm it can instantiate your mc properly...Then try parenting again?

Comment: ha just saw the answer below... cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you set as the "Class" in your Export for ActionScript settings? It looks like you're trying to refer to an *instance* rather than the class itself. For example, `mc` is an *instance* of the `MovieClip` *Class*.

Assuming you've chosen the Class "SequenceA", you would do this instead:

```
var seqA:SequenceA = new SequenceA();
```

There's a little bit more detail about objects and classes [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9f.html).

Comment: Thanks, this actually works, but gives me the following error:

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property sequenceA not found on classes.Main and there is no default value.
 at classes::BeatModel/populateArrays()[C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Individual Project\classes\BeatModel.as:121]

Line 121 of BeatModel is an irrelevant array that isn't inside populateArrays

Comment: I'm guessing, but that sounds like you're referring to the old `sequenceA` that you had on the stage, where you actually want to declare `var seqA` above and refer to that instead now.

Comment: Sorry, thought it had worked but it didn't still getting the same error message (there was a line of code on 121 that still had sequenceA so i recapitalised it)

Comment: Don't worry sorted it out - I should have been referring to 'seqA'

Comment: Nice one. You get used to tracking down these error messages eventually.